# C++ - Fastest way to delete snapshots in Linux

Tags: c++, qemu, snapshot

I'm building an app that let's users clean their Desktop in the least amount of time.
I'm considering deleting snapshots. It seems like a good option

```
system("sudo apt-get install qemu-utils"); // 42 mb's
system("qemu-img snapshot -d");
```

The Code works great, but It needs to download 42 mb's which will destroy the purpose of the app (the least amount of time)

Is there a way to delete them without installing anything?

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd use a tool you don't have installed without installing it first. If you're using snapshots, you should have that tool already installed.

Comment: That's my problem. I need a way to do it without installing. Ty, i will edit

Comment: Either you're going to install it and use it, or you're not. I'm not sure what you're asking here. It's like saying "How do I run an operating system without installing it?"

Comment: So it's impossible to run a code that delete things without using the terminal commands? How is "qemu-img" removing them in the first place?

Comment: qemu should not remove them (uninstall qemu-utils) with the commands specified. Something else is going on.

Comment: Unless you want to re-implement the internals of that program, you're going to need to install it. It's not that you can't delete things, C++ has functions for deleting files and directories, it's that you're *specifically* asking to manipulate QEMU snapshots, something that you need special tools to do.

Comment: I'm surprised you're able to use QEMU without this tool being installed. It seems like it should be there as part of the deployment.